# Entity Framework update entity with one to one relation

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship

I have two entities:

```
public class Tournament
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual TournamentSite Site { get; set; }
}

public class TournamentSite
{
    [Key]        
    public Int32 Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and in DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tournament>()
                    .HasRequired<TournamentSite>(t => t.Site)
                    .WithRequiredDependent()
                    .Map(p => p.MapKey("IdSite"));

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

everything is working fine, I mean when I load a tournament it gets the TournamentSite with proper Id and Name the problem is I want to change a TournamentSite for a specific Tournament. I have tried something like this:

```
var tournament = dbContext.Tournaments.Find(1); // Get tournament with id 1
tournament.Site.Id = 2;

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I expect that in the Tournament table the IdSite field to be 2 now instead of 1, but whatever I do the IdSite field that is used to link Tournament to TournamentSite it's always 1.

Any help is welcome,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to do it, I have redone the models like this:

```
public class Tournament
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Int32 IdSite { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdSite")]
    public virtual TournamentSite Site { get; set; }
}

public class TournamentSite
{
    [Key]        
    public Int32 Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Nothing needs to be done in OnModelCreating the function looks like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

and now I can use:

```
var tournament = dbContext.Tournaments.Find(1);
tournament.IdSite = 2;

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to actually map IdSite to your Tournament object like so

```
public class Tournament
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 TournamentSiteId { get; set;}
    public virtual TournamentSite Site { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tournament>()
                    .HasRequired<TournamentSite>(t => t.Site)
                    .WithRequiredDependent()
                    .Map(p => p.MapKey("IdSite"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tournament>()
                    .Property(p => p.TournamentSiteId)
                    .HasColumnName("IdSite");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Now you should be able to do this

```
var tournament = dbContext.Tournaments.Find(1); // Get tournament with id 1
tournament.TournamentSiteId = 2;

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

et voila!

Comment: If I use this I get: 

Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'IdSite' was already defined."

Comment: Oh sorry...take out the Map from the first statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to change the ID of the `TournamentSite`, not the `IdSite` of the `Tournament`. You'll need to assign the `Site` property instead:

```
var tournament = dbContext.Tournaments.Find(1);
tournament.Site = dbContext.TournamentSites.Find(2);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I have tried:
tournament.Site = dbContext.TournamentSites.Find(2);

but after dbContext.SaveChanges(); IdSite field is still 1 nothing is changing in the table.